# IIS 7.5 - no default site / no http binding

Tags: iis

I enabled/installed IIS on my win 7 home premium hoping to be able to run asp pages on my comp.

There are two issues that I don't know how address:

1- I don't see the Default Website in the IIS Manager
2- I don't have http option under binding

This is what I did...

I enabled/installed IIS 7.5

Control Panel - Programs - Turn Windows Features On or Off
checked everything under "Intenet Information Services"
checked everything under "Intenet Information Services Hostable Web Core"

I open the IIS Manager and see three panes (windows):

Connections on the left
Features or Content view in the middle section
Actions on the right

This is my question # 1: Any idea why I don't see any default site in the connections pane?

Server name
Application Pools
Sites (folder)
************ nothing here !!! ************

My question #2 relates to binding... when I want to set up a new site, I do the following:

(in Actions pane) - add web site 
site name: 
app pool: ASP .NET v4.0
Physical path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testsite

Under binding type, these are the options that I see... but there's no http option available.

Binding type:
- net.tcp
- net.pipe
- net.msmq
- msmq.formatname

Any idea why and/or what to do to have http option available?

I should probably mention that I am running xampp 1.8.0 on my comp as well on port 80.
127.0.0.1:80.

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: No, I didn't manage to find the answer for this....I actually ended up upgrading my OS to Win7 Professional and the issue was resolved in the upgraded version...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue and the only solution was:

1. Remove WAS (Windows Activation Services)
2. Remove IIS
3. Reboot
4. Install WAS
5. Install IIS
6. Reboot
7. open the IIS and see the default web site with both HTTP and HTTPS bindings