# Windows 7 Home IIS 7.5 Binding not available

Tags: windows, iis-7.5

[image]

Hi everyone, I need your help in figureing out IIS 7.5.

I have IIS installed on my windows 7 64x home and WAS is also enabled.
When i try to add a new website , the Binding Type list seems to be empty.
What could be the problem.
I tried uninstalling both the IIS and WAS, restarted the machine and installed both again and still no luck.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097446/iis-7-5-no-default-site-no-http-binding

Comment: @JacodeGroot still no luck

Comment: You may have to upgrade to Windows 7 Professional.

Comment: Is there anything special about your network adapters?